# Unable to hide Bottom Navigation View in Android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am working on an android app with BottomNavigationView. I want to hide the bottom nav view on page scroll and want to show it again when scroll stops. Below is what i have tried so far, but it isnt working. I have even tried programatical approach of doing with BottomNavViewBhaviour class, but that also didnt worked. Can someone kindly help.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layoutToolbar"
            layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"

        app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_navigation_view"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_9dp"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="@dimen/_10dp"
        app:itemPaddingTop="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavTextStyle"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavTextStyle"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_menu_text_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```